# Using cartopy to plot a binary map of Earth

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to use cartopy to plot a map of Earth with only 2 colors. The lands, filled in white and the ocean in dark for example. For now, I use the coastlines() method that creates the contour of the continents, but i don't know how to fill them with a colour, or to fill the ocean with one.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
 ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection = ccrs.EckertIV())
 ax.clear()
 cs = ax.contourf(longitude,lattitude,A,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    cmap='gist_gray',alpha=0.3)#,extend = 'both')
 ax.coastlines(color = 'black')
```

It produces a map with the continents, but it is all white, except the coastlines in black.
Any thoughts on how to fill continents and/or oceans with a color ?
I've thought about using the stock_img() method but it does not uniformly fill the land with one colour.

Thank you in advance !

PS : this is my first post so please tell me if you need more precision on my problem or if I need to edit my post in a certain way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example. In your example, you didn't show what is your `longitude`, `latitude` and `A` data, so I just replaced with a simple line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

latitude = [0, 10]
longitude = [0, 20]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.EckertIV())

ax.set_global()
# set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.patch.set_facecolor(color='black')
# or
# ax.background_patch.set_facecolor(color='black')   # cartopy < v0.18
# or
# ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, color='black')

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, color='white')

ax.plot(longitude, latitude, color='red', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

You are using an EckertIV projection, so you have to inform the axis that your longitude and latitude values are referenced to a `PlateCarree` projection. That's why you have to use the `crs` kw in `set_extent` (if not using `set_global`) and the `transform` kw in `plot`.

[image]

Comment: Whoua, thank you a lot. I didn't know about the patch.set_facecolor function, and it will be super useful!

Comment: Hello @Zeyta, if this answer solves your problem, please mark the answer as correct (the green check image).

Comment: Also, instead of changing the axes background color with `ax.patch.set_facelor` you could also just use the OCEAN layer: `ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, color='black')`

Comment: @marceolandrioni yes I marked it as correct, thanks for reminding me. I'll try playing around with the OCEAN layer but your first answer is already sufficient for what I need to do! Thank you again